# Can we load ascx or aspx page using angularjs into html

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, sharepoint

Can we load ascx or aspx page using angularjs into html control ?

This is the structure I have,

> SharePoint MasterPage
>
> > SharePoint Webpart
> >
> > > Html page (partial view)
> > >
> > > > How to load ascx or aspx page here ?>

Now I need to load aspx or acsx page dynamically.

**WorkAround 1**

I can think of one work around, which is to load this user control in SharePoint Webpart then hide it, and only show when needed, but I think there might be an easier way...

**WorkAround 2**

using IFrame I load the page.

***Is there any better way ?***

Comment: Please provide more detail and any code you have tried. Without more information there are too many possible answers.  Do you have control of the SharePoint back end or must this all be done client side? Are the child aspx pages tied to a master page? What do you mean by "upload aspx" page dynamically?  What version of SharePoint?

Comment: @Roberto can you give me one of the possible answer out of so many please ? :)